# div disappears after position: relative

Tags: css, html

I'm trying to position an image to the right within a container. However, after I set my parent container to `position: relative;`, my image disappears. Any ideas? Website: http://andrewgu12.kodingen.com/. Thanks!

CSS:

```
.slide {
    padding-top: 138px;
    background-attachment: fixed;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    position: relative;
        box-shadow:inset 0px 10px 10px rgba(0,0,0,0.3); 
}
div#inner-container {
    text-align: left;
    width: 960px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    padding: 0;
    white-space: normal;
    position: relative;
}
div#name {
    right: 0;
    bottom: 200px;
    position: absolute;
}
```

HTML:

```
<div class="slide" id="home" data-slide="1" data-stellar-background-ratio="1">
        <div id="inner-container">
            <div id="name" clas="row">
                <img src="images/names.png">
            </div>                            
        </div>            
    </div>
```

Comment: I think it has to do with the position absolute of the name div.

Comment: I set the position to be absolute so that it would stay at the bottom of the page hovering right above the green block.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

It does not disappear, it just goes all the way up and out the monitor xD You have to remember that when you use `position: absolute` the object is going to look for a parent that has `position: relative` to position itself. When you add `position: relative` to `div#inner-container` it changes the `div#name.row` reference. Maybe adding `height: 100%;` to the parent `div` might do the trick for what you want?

Comment: That did it, thanks! Can you explain why I have to add the height: 100% though?

Comment: `position:absolute` is relative to the nearest `position: relative` parent. That `div` had no height, so it kinda had no bottom, the bottom was at the top of the page. Using `height: 100%` actually makes that `div` the same height as it content.

Comment: Not doing the trick for me. The position absolute gets removed every time I scroll to the end or top.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
div#name {
    position:fixed;
    right: 0px;
    bottom: 200px;

}
```

Comment: Is there any way to set the 'div#name' to float to the very right of the '#inner-container' rather than '#container'?

Comment: Position:fixed is a lovely alternative here

Answer (score 0):

I Solved it! The parent div that has position:relative actually goes really high up the monitor. So you need to set the the top style to 0px and play around with the top,bottom,right,left styles that come with position relative. So basically add (top: 0px) to your css styling.